# Extending struct with type erasure apprach to avoid major refactoring

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-erasure

I am writing from existing (not my) code. It uses `Path` (i.e. `using Path = std::vector<Point>;`) everywhere. `Point` has no functionality. It just stores data. One of the methods takes `Path`, filters out the points, and returns a new `Path`.

```
Path filter(cosnt Path& path) {... return filteredPath; }
```

During filtering, I want to add additional information describing the point (such as how the point was calculated). So, I want to have something like `PointExt : Point` (there are might be additional types). Doing so will require me to change to `using Path = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Point>>` and change code in many places. I'm thinking of using type erasure instead. Thus, I can change only in places where I really need to cast to `PointExt` and get the extra information.

By doing so I thought I could keep the current usage of adding `Point` to `Path` and I could also add `PointExt`.

```
Path path;
path.push_back(Point());
path.push_back(PointExt());
```

I converted `Point` to type erasure as shown below and defined `PointExt : Point`. But, I get `attempting to reference a deleted function` error.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is my solution a reasonable way to solve this problem or is it ridiculous?

**CODE**

```
struct Point
{
    template<typename T>
    Point(T&& p): object(std::make_shared<Model<T>>(std::forward<T>(p))) {}

    virtual PointType getType() const { return object->getType(); }
  
    struct Concept
    {
        virtual ~Concept() {}
        virtual PointType getType() const = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct Model : Concept
    {
        Model(const T& t) : object(t) {}
        T object;
        PointType getType() const override { return object.getType(); }
    };

    int x;
    int y;
    std::shared_ptr<Concept> object;
};

struct PointExt : Point
{
   PointType getType() const override { return PointType::PointExt ; }
    
   std::vector<Solution> solutions;
};

struct PointExt2 : Point
{
   PointType getType() const override { return PointType::PointExt2 ; }
    
   ...
};
```

**UPDATE**

I found the reason for the error `attempting to reference a deleted function` . I forgot default constructor in `Point`. So, once I added `Point() = default;` it fixed the error.

Comment: `path.push_back(PointExt());` will slice the object to a `Point`. The full verbatim error message would be useful.

Comment: This all sounds horrible.  I'd just make strategic use of `using`  to make any future refactoring as easy as possbile.

Comment: I generally like refactoring because it usually means I get to delete code and I'm all about that, but sometimes it is just a chore. The longer you try to avoid it the worse it will be when you are forced to do it because you can't add one more domino without them all falling.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, it will not slice to `Point`. The `Point` has reference to templated `object` which holds the actual object.

Comment: @PaulSanders, why is this horrible? Assuming I cannot refactor (since it's a lot and not my code) this solves what I need. This gives me an option to have different types of `Point` that I can still insert into `Path`. I can add `as<T>()` function that will return me the actual type. And I found the reason for the error. I forgot default .ctor in `Point`

Comment: I refer you to @RetiredNinja's second comment.  You're building on sand.

Comment: "once I added `Object() = default;` it fixed the error" > did you mean `Point() = default;`? It sounds like you are already thinking more about generic objects than points, even though a path really is just a sequence of points.

Comment: Pretty sure your second question is off-topic (opinion-based). However, I totally agree with @PaulSanders and @RetiredNinja here. Additional information such as "how the point was calculated" has no place in a `Path`. It's metadata. I would just use a separate container to store it alongside a path whenever I need it, and I would keep `Path` as simple as possible.